# Does $ \sum_a P(a|b,c)P(d|a) = P(d|b,c)$?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, discrete-distributions

I saw it applied in a textbook once, but can't seem to figure out why or if it holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you have that
$$P(d\mid b,c) = \sum_a P(a,d\mid b,c) = \sum_a P(a\mid b,c)P(d\mid a,b,c)$$
but whenever the conditional independence $D \perp B,C \mid A$ holds you have that $P(d\mid a,b,c) = P(d\mid a)$ and your formula is correct. However in most cases it is not true.